# How to parse HTML content in a Spring Boot app

Tags: javascript, java, html

I have a project that allows a user to post HTML content to an endpoint. The program is supposed to process the HTML content and create a new HTML file on the server. The client constructs an HTML string which is then posted to an endpoint. The endpoint calls a service method which writes the file.

Expected:
The client posts the HTML string to the endpoint ``. The service process the HTML content from the body. Then an HTML file is created with the html content

Actual:
The client posts the HTML string to the endpoint `wordmatch`. The service process the HTML content from the body. Then an HTML file is created with the HTML content, but there is an error copying the string sections

```
</div><span style="padding: 3px"> <button id ="one" class="button" type="button" onClick="show_answer(">Show Answer</button> <button id = "resetButton" class="button" type="button" onClick="reset(">Reset</button></span>
```

The generated HTML string is created like so

```
 // initialize blank html
        header = '<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n\t<head>\n\t\t<title>Word Matching Exercise</title>\n\t\t<style>\n*:focus {outline: 2px solid blue; outline-offset: 2px;}\n\t\tdetails {padding:3px;}\n\t\t</style>\n\t\t<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/css/boxes.css\" />\n\t\t<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/event1.js\">';
        header += "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/css/style.css\" />"
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>\n'
        header += '<script async src=\"https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-89940905-27\">'
        // header += '</'
        // header += 'script>\n<script>\n\t window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];\n\t function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};\tgtag(\"js\", new Date());\tgtag(\"config\", \"UA-89940905-27\");\n'
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>\n'
        header += '<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">'
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>\n'
        header += '<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery-ui.min.js">'
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>\n'
        header += '<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js">'
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>\n'
        header += '<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/event1.js">'
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>\n'
        header += '<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery.alerts.js">'
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>\n'
        header += '<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">'
        header += '<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/logging.js\">'
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>\n</head>\n\t\t<body>';
        let html = '';
        html += header;
        html += '<div id=\'maincontentstyle\'>\n'
        html += '\t<center>\n'
        html += '\t\t<div id=\'boxstyle\'>\n'
        html += '\t\t\t<h3 id=\'title\'>'+title+"</h3>\n";
        //create key inputs
        html += '\t\t\t\t<center>\n'
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\'source\'>\n' 
        for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < elArray.length+numberOfInputs; i++){
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t\t<div id=\'s';
        id   = (1+i-numberOfInputs);
        html += id;
        html +='\' class=\'draggyBox-small ui-draggable\'>\n';
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
        html += elArray[i-numberOfInputs]
        html += '\n';
        html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n';
        }
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n'
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t</center>\n'

        //create description inputs
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t<table id=\'tablestyle\'>\n'
        console.log(dlArray)
        dlArray = shuffle(dlArray);
        console.log(dlArray)
        for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < dlArray.length+numberOfInputs; i++){
        html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\n'
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t\t<td id=\'row';
        id   = (1+i-numberOfInputs);
        html += id;
        html +='\'>\n';
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div id=\'t';
        html += id;
        html +='\' class=\'ltarget\'>'
        html +='</div>\n' 
        html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t</td >\n'
        html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t<td id=\'d'
        html += id
        html += '\'>\n'
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t';
        html += dlArray[i-numberOfInputs];
        html += '\n';
        html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td >\n' 
        html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr>\n';
        }
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t</table>\n';
        html += '\t\t\t\t</center>\n'
        html += '\t\t</div>\n'
        html += '\t</center>\n'
        html += '</div>'
        html += '<span style=\"padding: 3px\"> <button id =\"one\" class=\"button\" type=\"button\" onClick=\"show_answer'
        html += '()'
        html += '"'
        html += ">"
        html += 'Show Answer'
        html += '</'
        html += 'button> <button id = \"resetButton\" class=\"button\" type=\"button\" onClick=\"reset'
        html += '()'
        html += '"'
        html += '>'
        html += 'Reset'
        html += '</'
        html += 'button>'
        html += '</span>'
        footer = '\n\t\t</body>\n</html>\n';
        footer += '<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/word_match.js\">'
        footer += '</'
        footer += 'script>'
        footer += '<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/GetElementPosition3.js\">'
        footer += '</'
        footer += 'script>'
        footer += '<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js\">'
        footer += '</'
        footer += 'script>'
        footer += '<script>audioOn = false; $(function() {$(\'.menulink\').click(function(){if (audioOn) {$("#bg").attr(\'src\',\"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/images/audioOff.png\");  audioOn = false;}else {$(\"#bg\").attr(\'src\',"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/images/audioOn.png");audioOn = true; speak(" ");}return false;});});'
        footer += '</'
        footer += 'script>'
        footer += '<img id=\"bg\" src=\"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/images/audioOff.png\" height=\"30\" width=\"30\" style=\"margin-bottom:-10px; padding-bottom:-20px;\">'
        html += footer;
```

The server receives the string as

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
        <head>
                <title>Word Matching Exercise</title>
                <style>
*:focus {outline: 2px solid blue; outline-offset: 2px;}
                details {padding:3px;}
                </style>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/css/boxes.css" />
                <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/event1.js"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/css/style.css" /></script>
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-89940905-27"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/event1.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery.alerts.js"></script>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"><script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/logging.js"></script>
</head>
                <body><div id='maincontentstyle'>
        <center>
                <div id='boxstyle'>
                        <h3 id='title'>title</h3>
                                <center>
                                        <div class='source'>
                                                <div id='s1' class='draggyBox-small ui-draggable'>
                                                        k1
                                                </div>
                                                <div id='s2' class='draggyBox-small ui-draggable'>
                                                        k2
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </center>
                                        <table id='tablestyle'>
                                                <tr>
                                                <td id='row1'>
                                                        <div id='t1' class='ltarget'></div>
                                                </td >
                                                <td id='d1'>
                                                        d2
                                                        </td >
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                <td id='row2'>
                                                        <div id='t2' class='ltarget'></div>
                                                </td >
                                                <td id='d2'>
                                                        d1
                                                        </td >
                                                </tr>
                                        </table>
                                </center>
                </div>
        </center>
</div><span style="padding: 3px"> <button id ="one" class="button" type="button" onClick="show_answer(">Show Answer</button> <button id = "resetButton" class="button" type="button" onClick="reset(">Reset</button></span>
                </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/word_match.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/GetElementPosition3.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script><img id="bg" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/images/audioOff.png" height="30" width="30" style="margin-bottom:-10px; padding-bottom:-20px;">
```

The issue is at `onClick="show_answer(">Show Answer`. For some reason the parenthesis is getting chopped off. The data model is

```
import lombok.Data;


@Data
public class WordMatch {
    
    public String content;
}
```

Why is the string losing the other parenthesis? The code is at https://github.com/EvanGertis/Selected-Topics.git. The command `mvn spring-boot:run` should start the project up.

Comment: Please base64 the HTML string before posting it to your backend.  You can then decrypt it without facing these problems with special brackets...

Comment: Can you share some details on your controller as well as how the client is calling it? Did you check where the string gets "corrupted"? Maybe this is already hitting a limit on the client's end (e.g. if you're putting the content into a query parameter instead of a POST body).

Comment: Btw, please do not post links to code but post relevant portions directly here. Links may break, the content may change, firewalls might block github, people might not trust the links etc.